# Dynamically creating static routes from database using Next JS

Tags: server, next.js

I'm trying to understand how Next JS does dynamic routing and I'm a little confused on how to properly implement it in my own website. Basically, I have a database (MySQL) of content that keeps growing, let's say they're blog posts, with images stored in GCS. From what I understand you can create a `pages/[id].js` file in your pages folder that can handle dynamically creating routes for new pages, but, in order for you to get a good SEO score you, the Google crawlers need to see your content before any javascript or data requests are made. So the pages have to be physically available for the content to instantly appear upon loading. So if I have `pages/[id].js` and I have content added to the database daily, how are physical content files supposed to spontaneously populate the `pages` folder? And if `pages` files keep getting created, how do I prevent my disk from running out of space? I'm sure there is something I'm not understanding.

I read on nextjs.org that you can have a function `getStaticPaths` that [needs to return a list of possible values for 'id'](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/dynamic-routes/page-path-external-data). I'm wondering, if my site is live and new content (pages) is constantly being added to the database with their own unique ids, how is it "aware" of those ids? Do I need to write a program or message queue system that constantly appends new ids to a file that is read by `getStaticPaths`? What if I have to duplicate my site on multiple servers around the world, or if a server dies, do I have to keep track of the file's contents in order to boot up a new server with the same content?

From what I understand, in order for Google to see any sort of content on your website, the pages text (content) needs to be static and quickly available via physical files. Images and everything else can be loaded later since Google's crawlers mainly care about text. So if every post needs to be a physical file in your app's `pages` folder, how do new `pages` files get created if the content is added to the database?

TL:DR My main concern is having my content readily available for Google crawlers in order to get a good score for my website. How do I achieve that if content is added to my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated before, you can set up `getStaticPaths` to provide a list of values for  `id` at build time. If I understand correctly, you are most concerned about what happens to new content added after the initial build.
For this you have to return the [`fallback` key](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required) from getStaticPaths.

If the fallback key is `false`, then all IDs not specified initially will go to `404` and you’d need to rebuild the app every time you add new content. This is what you don't want.
If you set it to `true`, then the initial values will be prerendered just like before, but new values will NOT go `404`. Instead, the first user visiting a path with a new `Id` will trigger the rendering of that new page. This allows you to dynamically check for new content if a request hits an `id` that wasn't available at build time.

It is interesting here that the first visitor will temporarily see a [‘fallback’-version of the page](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-pages), while next.js processes the request. On that fallback, you would usually just show a loading spinner. The server then passes the data to the client in order to properly render the full page. So in practice, the user will first see a loading indicator, then the page updates itself with the actual content. Subsequent visitors will get the now prerendered result immediately.

You may now be worried about crawlers hitting that fallback page and not getting SEO content. This concern has been addressed here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12482

Apart from being able to serve new pages after build, the fallback strategy has another use in that it allows you to prerender only a small subset of your website (like your most visited pages), while the other pages will be generated only when necessary.

[From the docs: When is fallback: true useful?](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-is-fallback-true-useful)

> You may statically generate a small subset of pages and use fallback:
> true for the rest. When someone requests a page that’s not generated
> yet, the user will see the page with a loading indicator. Shortly
> after, getStaticProps finishes and the page will be rendered with the
> requested data. From now on, everyone who requests the same page will
> get the statically pre-rendered page.
> This ensures that users always have a fast experience while preserving
> fast builds and the benefits of Static Generation.

Comment: So in order to have a some pages available for crawling after the initial build, I would use getStaticPaths which will tell Next to use prerendered pages from a list of IDs. From my understanding, if I were to rebuild the site at a later date, or a new page wasn't yet prerendered, that's when getStaticProps is used to grab, say, the top viewed articles for my front page by making whatever necessary requests to my DBs. My last concern is what happens with old prerendered content that hasn't been viewed in a long time? Can I set params to dynamically delete old content to free up my disk/memory?

Comment: That's correct. However, I don't think there is anything you can do to remove old prerendered pages, besides rebuilding. If you are seriously concerned about this, you could make use of getServerSideProps instead. Then the server renders the pages on each request and doesn't save the prerendered output.

Comment: Hmm, that's a shame. I was wondering I could at least have something like a cron job that periodically flushes out old articles, but I'm mainly concerned with no experience so it might not even be an issue.

Comment: You could probably do a cron job to trigger a rebuild when the server runs out of resources, but I doubt that's necessary in most cases and as far as I know common hosting services like Vercel Now do not have a limit on the number of pages that can be generated.